# JS animation does not make div bigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a div bigger when the user clicks on it. I know that I acces the function because I get the alert message "End of the animation". I want to make my div as big as the page.
This is my css code:

```
.item {
        flex: 0 25%;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 2%; /* (100-32*3)/2 */
        height: 200px;
        box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background-color: #C15D5D;;
        background-size: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
      
    }

    .item.green,#green-item{
      background:#71B083;
      position:relative;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

And this is my HTML code

```
    <div onclick="anim()" class="item green" id="green-item">
        <div class="ellipse green"></div>
        <p class= "price">225€</p>
        <img src="glasses1.png" class="glasses1">
        <pre class="text1">Black Gold Imogene
        </pre>
    </div>
<script type="application/javascript">
        object = document.getElementById("green-item");
        function anim(){
            object.style.width = "40%"; 
            object.style.height = "auto"; 
            object.style.transition = "width 0.5s ease"; 
            alert("End of the animation"); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want it to do -- this snippet should do it? Try using the 'vh' and 'vw' (view height/view width) css units. Also, I added an `* {  margin: 0 }` style to remove margins and get it right to the edge to 'make as big as the page'

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}
.item {
        flex: 0 25%;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 2%; /* (100-32*3)/2 */
        height: 200px;
        box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background-color: #C15D5D;;
        background-size: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
      
    }

    .item.green,#green-item{
      background:#71B083;
      position:relative;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div onclick="anim()" class="item green" id="green-item">
  <div class="ellipse green"></div>
  <p class="price">225€</p>
  <img src="glasses1.png" class="glasses1">
  <pre class="text1">
    Black Gold
    Imogene
  </pre>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">
  object = document.getElementById("green-item");

  function anim() {
    object.style.width = "100vw";
    object.style.height = "100vh";
    object.style.transition = "width 0.5s ease";
    alert("End of the animation");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work but it only goes down vertically (maybe because of my flex box). Also, there is no expansion animation. it only changes from small to bill